# Keras LSTM How to loop for predict by model.predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to predict lstm 7 time. I have to get output from model.predict() and use the output to predict again to 7 time.

This is code.

```
data = 0
y_pred=0

data[0] = model.predict(X_test_t)

for i in range(7):

    data[i+1] = model.predict(data[i])

print(data)
```

when I run it show error like this

```
  File "test_load_model.py", line 60, in <module>
    data[0] = model.predict(X_test_t)

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

How to loop for prediction?

Comment: Data is initialized to be an integer. You probably want to say data =[] and instead of indexing, append to the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a list for your data. Currently it is an int and you can't index an int.
So you need to do

```
data =[]
```

And to append you do

```
data.append(model.predict(data[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store values by indexing. Create a list and append items to your list using "variable name".append()